# Hbase one to many relationship using versions

Tags: nosql, hbase

I have been using `HBase` with some sample DNS data.  My idea is quite simple is using `HBase`'s revision/VERSION scheme to make a one to many relationship. This is mainly to simplify loading and management of data.  Here is a sample of my design

A-Records table

```
ROW:  www.example.com
IP:  1.1.1.1
TIMESTAMP: 1388922331000
VERSION : 1

IP:  1.1.1.7
TIMESTAMP: 1388940991000
VERSION: 2
```

My Hbase table looks like

```
hbase>create table 'a', 'ip'

hbase> alter 'a', { NAME => 'ip', VERSIONS => 100 }
```

When you query for all rows of www.example.com in base shell or using

```
hbase> get 'a', 'www.example.com, { COLUMNS => 'ip', VERSIONS => 100 }
```

I get all the results back.  I can iterate through them in a RESTFUL API and provide user the experience of one to many table.

Experts in HBase see any issues with this design?

Answer (score 0):

Your design is OK. I know some system's design just like yours.

BTW, if you use java. I am writing a framework which can mapping one row with multi-version to a list of DO. Which maybe help you.

https://github.com/zhang-xzhi/simplehbase